# Android Studio generated signed apk issue

Tags: android, sign

Here is my trouble: In debug mode, every thing is OK; When I build the APK only using V1(Jar Signature), it could not be installed. if I build the APK  using both V1(Jar Signature) and V2(Full apk signature), it could be installed and work ,but one activity would crash , the wrong line in Logcat  is strange and I can't find where is the bug. I am stuck for days, any help? Thank you.

Comment: maybe you set `minifyenabled true` in gradle file. So you need to add proguard rules  also.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend signing your .apk with both V1 and V2.  Q: Please update your post with the specific Logcat exception (most importantly, the relevant snippets of your stack traceback.

Comment: Thank you,  Chirag Savsani ! You saved me! and thank you, paulsm4.

Comment: Welcome. Always happy to help.